# Plotting complex power series in matlab or c++

Tags: matlab, plot

As part of my tutorial, I would like to show the plots of  a) sum 1/n z^n, b)Log(z)=log|z|+i Arg(z) to drive home the point of analytic continuation.

Plotting the second is easy but not the second one. Any suggestions for Matlab, mathematica or c++?

So far I've been trying with the symbolic sum function, but it was too heavy for my machine. I might leave it for few hours to run.

Any quicker ways? Here is a graph of a natural boundary image I found online to get an idea (not enough rep to post).

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1b/Natural_boundary_example.gif

Comment: "Plotting the second is easy but not the second one". So which one is it?

Comment: To clarify, in a) do you mean sum from 1 to n of z^n ?